# Unable to find a pane inside a pane through winium.desktop.driver. Unable to identify elements inside the pane

Tags: selenium, winium

Issue – Unable to find a pane inside a pane through winium.desktop.driver. Hence, unable to identify elements inside the pane.

Below are some of the details which may help.

I am using Selenium Java binding.

Application is a desktop application having embedded HTML elements. As per my understanding, there are Pages / Frames being displayed inside a Window. I am using winium desktop driver to accomplish test automation. Please below code.
Stack trace says “Element not found”.

My understanding is that pane2 is not being identified as it is inside pane1 thus I am unable to identify elements inside pane2. There are not sufficient unique attributes for pane2.

**Code:**

```
WebElement mainWindow = driver.findElement(By.id(‘WebBrowserForm’));

WebElement pane1 = mainWindow.findElement(By.xpath(“//*[@Name=’Contact: New Contact’][@LocalizedControlType=’pane’]”));

String p1 = pane1.getAttribute(“ProcessId”);

WebElement pane2 = pane1.findElement(By.xpath(“//*[@ProcessId=’” +p1+ ”’][ @LocalizedControlType=’pane’][@Name=’’]”));

WebElement el1 = pane2.findElement(By.xpath(“//*[@ProcessId=’” +p1+ ”’][ @LocalizedControlType=’text’][ @Name=’Suffix’]”));

el1.click();

Any help would be much appreciated.
```

[Inspect Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bli9D.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Which tool are you using to inspect the elements in the windows application?

Instead of using 'Process ID', try to use 'Automation ID'.

Comment: Better to use UI-Spy as the Inspector tool.

Comment: I used Inspect.exe. Please refer the attached screenshot. Automation ID is not available for the pane. UI Spy is also giving similar information. I am unable to move forward.

Comment: In the screenshot, I think the pane is below the link, you selected the link in the tree. What are the properties it is showing when select the pane in the tree?